# Is there a way to remove +/- from CLKRelativeDateTextProvider with offset style?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-3, apple-watch-complication

I'm using CLKRelativeDateTextProvider to provide a timer on my watch complication. It's a count down. All works great except for watchOS showing a negative sign. For example (depending whether it counts up or down):

> - 21 minutes
>   + 21 minutes

Is there a way to somehow format the text in the `CLKRelativeDateTextProvider` such that it only would show **21 minutes**? I couldn't find anything in the docs and online but maybe (i.e. hoping) I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you try using different CLKRelativeDateStyles to see if any of them worked for you? Other than that, I don't see anything in the docs that allows you to customize the format further.

Comment: Yes, I did. I think I'll just have to adjust design a little. Thanks.